# For loop prints in terminal instead Of in excel file

Tags: python, linux, vim, openpyxl

Let me just start off with a disclaimer: I'm terrible at python but I'm willing to learn.
I'm trying to create a python script that creates a username as well as a password for 33 people in an existing excel-file(**names.xslx**). But whenever I try to import the usernames they all just print in the terminal instead of the excel file.

I've tried finding a solution online but I just haven't managed to find one. I also tried entering each username manually like so:

```
ws['E2'] = (username(5))                                                        
ws['E3'] = (username(5))
```

etc.. which worked, but it occupied 30 rows and was way too time consuming, so I tried creating a loop but it won't work...

```
  1 import random                                                                   
  2 import string                                                                   
  3 from openpyxl import workbook                                                   
  4 from openpyxl import load_workbook                                              
  5                                                                                 
  6 wb = load_workbook('names.xlsx')                                                
  7 ws = wb.active                                                                  
  8                                                                                 
  9 def password(stringLength=8):                                             
 10     lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits                     
 11     return ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))
 12                                                                                 
 13 def username(stringLength=5):                                                   
 14     lettersAndDigits = string.ascii_letters + string.digits                     
 15     return ''.join(random.choice(lettersAndDigits) for i in range(stringLength))
 16                                                                                 
 17 cell_range =ws["E2":"E34"]                                                      
 18 cell_range2 =ws["F2":"F34"]                                                     
 19                                                                                    
 20 for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=5, max_row=34):                      
 21     for cell in row:                                                            
 22         print(username(5))                                                      
 23                                                                                 
 24 for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_col=6, max_row=34):                      
 25   for cell in row:                                                              
 26      print(password(8))                                                         
 27 
 28 wb.save('names_mod.xlsx')
```

I expected the usernames to be printed out in the **names_mod.xsl** file but all the usernames just printed in the terminal like so:

```
wFcDK
vJuuD
G1vXj
xBuNbD4s
OnG5kBJK
CkjEPUs2
bSY0mByj
```

etc.. please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need use `print`.
You need write value in the cell

Something like this:

```
for cell in row:
    cell.value = username(5)
```

And add min_col parameter if you need to write ***username*** in 5th column and ***password*** in 6th column

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=5, max_col=5, max_row=34):                      
    for cell in row:                                                            
        cell.value = username(5)                                                    

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=6, max_col=6, max_row=34):                      
    for cell in row:                                                              
        cell.value = password(8)
```

Comment: There is several options for write value in the cell, check doc https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/